# How To Replace OnActivityResult With New Activity Result API With Parse-SDK

Tags: android, facebook, kotlin, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I wonder if someone may be able to assist with my struggles, I apologise as I’m new to Kotlin.

After implementing facebook login following the `parse-sdk-android` documentation I have realised that `onActivityResult()` is deprecated (though it still works for the timebeing).

I am trying to adapt my code to work with the new Activity Result API’s (I saw a previous suggestion to use `registerForActivityResult`) however, my issue is that we are only calling the method `ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground` in the code and the activity being called is nested within this method.

I attempted to use `registerForActivityResult` to start the activity containing this method however it will only capture the result of the activity started and not that of the nested activity within `ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground` (which is the expected behaviour). Online searches have not brought back any results for a way to implement this for `parse-sdk-android`.

So my question is whether there is a way to capture the result of the nested activity using just the method ? without being able to change the nested code.

My code for logging in currently is as below:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        loginFacebook()

    }


    private fun loginFacebook(){

        val permissions: List<String> = listOf("public_profile", "email")
        ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this,permissions) { user: ParseUser?, err: ParseException? ->
            when {
                err != null -> {
                    Log.e("FacebookLoginExample", "done: ", err)
                    Toast.makeText(this, err.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                user == null -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "The user cancelled the Facebook login.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    Log.d("FacebookLoginExample", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
                }
                user.isNew -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "User signed up and logged in through Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    Log.d("FacebookLoginExample", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                    getUserDetailFromFB()
                }
                else -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "User logged in through Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    Log.d("FacebookLoginExample", "User logged in through Facebook!")
                    showAlert("Oh, you!", "Welcome back!")

                }
            }

        }

    }
```